# end-of-buffer miscalculating in org-mode when folded

Tags: org-mode, point, file-local-variables

I have an Org Mode file that I would like to open folded and immediately put the point at the bottom of the file.

With `org-startup-folded` set to `t` and this as the first line

`# -*- eval: (end-of-buffer) -*-`

it seems to miscalculate. My best guess is that `end-of-buffer` calculates the number of characters **visible* and then moves that number of characters forward while counting all characters in the file, not just visible ones.

Could this be the case? And, if so, how to achieve the desired effect of moving point to the end of the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Function `end-of-buffer` is intended for interactive use only. `C-h f`...

But your real problem is that you are trying to evaluate a *variable* `end-of-buffer`. There's no variable `end-of-buffer` (unless you create one). There is instead a *function* `end-of-buffer`. The unbound-variable error isn't reported because this is done in a file-local-variables setting.

You can use `(end-of-buffer)` (calling the function), instead of `end-of-buffer` in the file-local-variables list.

However, that likely won't do what you want (which is unspecified in your question). The file-local-variables list is evaluated at the beginning of when the file is *loaded*. And function `end-of-buffer` acts in whatever buffer is current at that time.

---

This answers your *X* question of what's happening with what you tried. But you no doubt have a [*Y* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821) behind what you're trying. Specify that as a separate question post: **How can I do *Y*?**.

Comment: Apoligies, that was a typo. I amended it to (end-of-buffer) which was in my org file. it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: As @Drew points out `end-of-buffer` is `interactive-only`. However the problem persists when using the recommended `(goto-char (point-max))`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated why the file-local variable approach doesn't work (I suspect that their evaluation is followed by other code that resets point, but I'm not sure), but you can do what you want using a hook, specifically `find-file-hook`. All you have to do is create a function that does what you want and add it to the hook. The doc string for `find-file-hook` says:

> List of functions to be called after a buffer is loaded from a file.
> The buffer’s local variables (if any) will have been processed before the
> functions are called.  This includes directory-local variables, if any,
> for the file’s directory.

So, although it's not guaranteed, the function will be called later in time than the setting of local variables, so it has a better chance of *not* having something that runs afterwards undo its work.

Remember also that the functions in the hook are run sequentially, so in order to avoid any of *them* affecting `point`, we'll add our function at the *end* of the hook. Like this:

```el
(defun my/move-to-end ()
   (when (string= (buffer-file-name) "/path/to/desired/file.org")
      (goto-char (point-max)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my/move-to-end 90)
```

Setting the `depth` argument to 90 should put the function at the end of the hook at least for now: if somebody adds another function at the end of the hook with an equal (org bigger) depth, they will win. That's one problem here.

The other problem is that the hook is run on *every* `find-file` and we probably don't want `point` at the end for most files, so we limit `my/move-to-end` to check whether the file is the one we are interested in before acting.

This should work in almost all cases (see the caveats above for the qualification "almost"). But there is a better way to do it. The idea is to use a local variable setting to change the *local* value of `find-file-hook`. Then we don't have to worry about the hook running this function on other files, only on the one(s) where we set the hook locally.

Here's how that goes. The function does not need to worry about what buffer it's called from:

```el
(defun my/move-to-end ()
   (goto-char (point-max)))
```

Then we add this to the top of the file:

```org
# -*- eval: (add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my/move-to-end 90 t) -*-
#+STARTUP: folded

* foo
lorem ipsum
*bar
lorem ipsum
```

Then kill the buffer and reopen it with `C-x C-f`. The `t` at the end of the `add-hook` call (see its doc string with `C-h v add-hook`) says to modify the *local* value of the hook. So `find-file` opens the file and evaluates the local variables, thereby running the `add-hook` call which adds the function to the *local* value of the hook (do `C-h v find-file-hook` in the resulting buffer to verify that the local value is just `(t my/move-to-end)`). Then when the hook is run, the `t` says "run the global value of the hook" and then it runs `my/move-to-end`. There is no possibility of anybody sneaking another function at the end of the hook: we get the final word. And since only the local value of the hook is changed, we don't have to complicate the function to check where it is called from.